# How do you stop a user from repeatedly clicking a jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web-page with the following script

Javascript

```
function LinkClicked() {

    var stage = this.id;
    var stop = $('#ContentPlaceHolderMenu_txtDate').val();
    var nDays = $('#ContentPlaceHolderMenu_txtNumberOfDays').val();

    $("[id$='spinner']").show();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "...",
        data: "{stage:'" + stage + "',stop:'" + stop + "',nDays:'" + nDays + "'}",
        success: function (data) {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            PlotData(data.d);

        },
        error: function () {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            alert("An error occured posting to the server");
        }
    });

}
```

How do I stop the user from repeatedly clicking whilst the query is running? The call is from a cell in a grid and can't easily be disabled. Ideally, I'd like a way of doing it in the script without disabling the link on the DOM.

Here I clicked five times, and you can see five AJAX requests are sent. The page should disable the same call being repeatedly invoked whilst it is already running.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could put a `flag` when you call the ajax, and reset it in the callback

Comment: add a throttle, disable the event while the request is running, remove the button that activates it, etc.

Comment: Can you disable the button/link whatever when the call begins and only  enable on success/fail?

Comment: @ DavidB The call is coming from a link in a cell of a grid view, and if possible I'd like to not disable it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have an external variable tracking the state

```
var linkEnabled = true;
function LinkClicked() {
    if(!linkEnabled){
    return;
    }
    linkEnabled = false;
    var stage = this.id;
    var stop = $('#ContentPlaceHolderMenu_txtDate').val();
    var nDays = $('#ContentPlaceHolderMenu_txtNumberOfDays').val();

    $("[id$='spinner']").show();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "...",
        data: "{stage:'" + stage + "',stop:'" + stop + "',nDays:'" + nDays + "'}",
        success: function (data) {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            PlotData(data.d);
            linkEnabled =true;

        },
        error: function () {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            alert("An error occured posting to the server");
            linkEnabled = true;
        }
    });

}
```

This also has the advantage that you can choose to enable other effects of this function if you want, and only prevent the repeat ajax calls.

(Note that ideally you would want to stick the external variable in a closure or a namespace rather than making it a global).

Answer (score 2):

Disable a button when user clicks it, and set disabled to false when you get response from ajax.

Comment: The call is coming from a link in a cell of a grid view, and if possible I'd like to not disable it

Comment: You can control by javascript variable in this case.

Comment: you could remove the handler once the button is clicked, then add it again upon success.

Comment: Or bind the handler using event delegation, then make the button not match the delegation target selector while the request is being made.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable outside of the function with an initial value of false:

```
var pending = false;
```

When you make the request, you'd do:

```
if (pending == true) {return;}
pending = true;
```

This makes it stop if you're already running, and when the request is done:

```
pending = false;
```

Now even without a button, the request won't fire multiple times.

As a side note, your data doesn't need to be a string. You can just do:

```
data: {stage: stage, stop: stop, nDays: nDays}
```

Comment: If i create the data as you suggest, the server won't accept it. [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetGraphData(string stage, string stop, int nDays){ ...

Answer (score 1):

you can just check use this

```
var ajax_stat = false

function doing_ajax(){
if(ajax_stat) return;
ajax_stat = true;
var xmlRequest =  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "...",
    data: "{stage:'" + stage + "',stop:'" + stop + "',nDays:'" + nDays + "'}",
    success: function (data) {
        $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
        PlotData(data.d);

    },
    error: function () {
        $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
        alert("An error occured posting to the server");
        ajax_stat = false;
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code. it will not make multiple ajax calls.

```
function LinkClicked() {

    if($(window).data("ajaxRUnning")){
       return;
    }
    $(window).data("ajaxRUnning",true);
    var stage = this.id;
    var stop = $('#ContentPlaceHolderMenu_txtDate').val();
    var nDays = $('#ContentPlaceHolderMenu_txtNumberOfDays').val();

    $("[id$='spinner']").show();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "...",
        data: "{stage:'" + stage + "',stop:'" + stop + "',nDays:'" + nDays + "'}",
        success: function (data) {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            PlotData(data.d);
            $(window).data("ajaxRUnning",false);
        },
        error: function () {
            $("[id$='spinner']").hide();
            alert("An error occured posting to the server");
            $(window).data("ajaxRUnning",false);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `$(window).data()` - why that? Just use a simple variable.

Comment: @Bergi check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/.. it better to do with on `window` instead of `Object` which called that method..as there can be multiple elements which can trigger same call.

Comment: I know what it does. But just don't use `window` or `Object` or anything, but a simple variable!